# Bootstrap container child with fullwidth background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I have the gradient background of #section2 to be fullwidth (to fill the viewport in width)?
I use bootstrap and I would like to respect these constraints:

- no javascript
- not removing *container* class from <main>
- not adding horizontal scrolling (the background should not be wider than the viewport, even when a vertical scrollbar appears)

Maybe, is there a way to compensate the margins introduced by container and section?

```css
body * {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

section {
  height: 100px;
}

#section2 {
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, blue 0%, white 100%);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <main class="container">
    <section>section 1</section>
    <section id="section2">section 2</section>
    <section>section 3</section>
  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Puedo Elements` to do so:

```
#section2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, red 0%, yellow 100%);
}
```

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/OJRoaXZ

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is clever to use :before to create the absolutely positioned element! However width: 100vw does not work when a vertical scrollbar appears. To verify you can set section height to 1000px in your codepen: when the vertical scrollbar appears, 100vw becomes wider than the remaining viewport, which generates a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I have updated the code. Changed width to `width: 100%;`, now it is working perfectly.

Comment: Yes it works! I am surprised: when using width: 100%, shouldn't the width of the section2:before element be the same as its container (section2 which is narrower than the viewport)?!

Comment: `#section2:before` is `position: absolute;` and the container is not `position: relative;`.

Comment: If the container would have been `position: relative;` then the `: before` would have taken the length of the container. Here we have not specified relative position so the before align it with respect to the body which is position relative by default.

Comment: I understand, this is very clever. It also relies on top defaulting to auto, which I did not know! Thank you very much.

Comment: Now, suppose we want the gradient to cover the full height of section2, and we do not know this size in CSS (suppose it is not hardcoded to 1000px), what would be your approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227171/discussion-between-manas-khandelwal-and-louis-coulet).

Comment: We can approach this in better way:

Comment: First `pseudo-elements` need height, so somehow we need to give them height. As per my last code, `100px` was hardcoded 2 times. The better approach will be to give `:before` `height: inherit;` so it will inherit height from the `#section2` but it has no height specified so it will then inherit from the `<section>`. ID's have a higher specificity so it first went to the ID then the tag. This way we only need to specify the height once's. Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/VwKGgom